# What are the differences between a Frame Buffer Object and a Pixel Buffer Object in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

What is the difference between FBO and PBO? Which one should I use for off-screen rendering?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A [FBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) (Framebuffer object) is a target where you can render images other than the default frame buffer or screen.

A [PBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) (Pixel Buffer Object) allows *asynchronous* transfers of pixel data to and from the device.  This can be helpful to improve overall performance when rendering if you have other things that can be done while waiting for the pixel transfer.

Answer (score 90):

> What is the difference between FBO and PBO?

A better question is how are they similar. The only thing that is similar about them is their *names*.

A [Framebuffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) (note the capitalization: framebuffer is one word, not two) is an object that contains multiple images which can be used as render targets.

A [Pixel Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) is:

1. A [Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object). FBOs are *not* buffer objects. Again: framebuffer is one word.
2. A buffer object that is used for asynchronous [uploading/downloading of pixel data to/from images](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer).

If you want to render to a texture or just a [non-screen framebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Default_Framebuffer), then you use FBOs. If you're trying to read pixel data back to your application asynchronously, or you're trying to transfer pixel data to OpenGL images asynchronously, then you use PBOs.

They're nothing alike.

Comment: Let's just hope this gets up-voted above the pure-link answer and the (unfortunately accepted) wrong answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I checked, and the OP seems to still be a regular. So there's hope that it'll be accepted.

Answer (score 11):

I would read [VBOs, PBOs and FBOs](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2006/10/vbos-pbos-and-fbos.html):

> Apple has posted two very nice bits of
>   sample code demonstrating PBOs and
>   FBOs. Even though these are
>   Mac-specific, as sample code they're
>   good on any platoform because PBOs and
>   FBOs are OpenGL extensions, not
>   windowing system extensions.
>
> So what are all these objects? Here's
>   the situation:

Answer (score 6):

I want to highlight something.

**FBO** it not memory block. I think it look like struct of pointer. You Must attach Texture to FBO to use it. After attach Texture you now can draw to it for offscreen render or for second pass effect.

```
struct FBO{
AttachColor0 *ptr0;
AttachColor1 *ptr1;
AttachColor2 *ptr2;
AttachDepth  *ptr3;
};
```

In the other hand, **PBO** is memory block "block to hold type of memory. "Try to think of it as malloc of x size, then you can use memcpy to copy data from it to texture/FBO or to it".

- Why to use PBO?

Create intermediate memory buffer to interface with Host memory and not stop OpenGL drawing will upload texture to or from host.